# Why do I get a wrong XOR output

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography

I just started the cryptopals.com challenge and I'm already stuck at the second problem.. For some reason my output is wrong by only one character instead of 7 I get a 3 as the first number of my XOR operation.

Could you help me find the mistake in my code:

```
def XORfunction(input_1, input_2):
    bin_input_1 = hexToBinary(input_1)
    bin_input_2 = hexToBinary(input_2)

    # check if length of strings is the same for XOR compare or add "0" to the end
    if len(bin_input_1) != len(bin_input_2):

        if len(bin_input_1) > len(bin_input_2):
            number_length = len(bin_input_1)
            temp_input = list(bin_input_2)
            for x in xrange(0, number_length - len(bin_input_2)):
                temp_input.insert(0, "0")
            bin_input_2 = "".join(temp_input)

        if len(bin_input_1) < len(bin_input_2):
            number_length = len(bin_input_2)
            temp_input = list(bin_input_1)
            for x in xrange(0, number_length - len(bin_input_1)):
               temp_input.insert(0, "0")
            bin_input_1 = "".join(temp_input)
    solution = []
    # XOR is like a sum so if el1+el2 == 1 output is 1 else output is 0
    for x in xrange(0, len(bin_input_1) - 1):
        # the array is iterated from [0] to len(bin_input_1)-1 so the elements are calculated from last to first
        current_compare = int(bin_input_1[x]) + int(bin_input_2[x])
        if current_compare == 1:
            solution.insert(-1, "1")
        else:
            solution.insert(-1, "0")
    return dec_to_hex(int("".join(solution), 2))


# the final solution has to be converted from decimal to hexadecimal
def dec_to_hex(value):
    dictionary_hex = "0123456789abcdef"
    solution = []
    while value != 0:
        solution.insert(0, dictionary_hex[value % 16])
        value = value / 16
    return "".join(solution)


# Hex is converted to a binary string to make comparisons easy as the digits become easy to select as an array of chars
def hexToBinary(text):
    # first Hex is converted to decimal, then to binary (that needs to be sliced for a clean output), lastly it becomes a string
    return str(bin(int(text, base=16))[2:])


print XORfunction("1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c", "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965")

# expected output: 746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179
# my output:       346865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179
```

This is my first time posting, so any tip on formatting/on the code is welcome.

PS: I know I should be using libraries, but I want to figure out what is my mistake first

Comment: You may also want to learn about `str.rjust()`.

Comment: You are skipping the last byte in the inputs.

Comment: Your indentation is off; surely the `return dec_to_hex(int("".join(solution), 2))` is not indented to that extent.

Comment: Your code currently returns either `"1"` or `"0"`, because you put your `return` at the wrong indentation level.

Comment: i lost the indentation while copy pasting and made it manually

Comment: Don't indent manually. Copy, select the code lines in the editor, and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to have the editor manage the indentation for you.

Comment: i copy pasted, but the {} ruins it all..

Comment: It's best to paste code that doesn't use TAB characters, they can be messed up by the formatter.

Comment: @FerruccioBalestreri: then don't mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues:

- Your `hexToBinary()` function doesn't produce padded binary. `bin()` will not return 8 bits per byte; leading zeros are not included! As such, you are missing `000` from the start of the first string, `0` from the other. You try to compensate for this in your `XORfunction` function, but that only adds back 2 zeros, not 3.

  You could use the `str.format()` method instead to ensure that you get the right number of bits, zero padded:

  ```
  return '{:0{}b}'.format(int(text, base=16), len(text) * 4)
  ```

  The `b` formatting instruction tells `str.format()` to produce the binary representation of a number. `0` before the width means to zero-pad the number to the required length, and the `{}` placeholder for the length is taken from the `len(text) * 4` value, so 4 bits per hex character in the input.
- You are inserting the solution bits *before the last element in the list*. This leaves the very first bit right at the end of your solution, with everything else inserted before it:

  ```
  >>> demo = []
  >>> demo.insert(-1, 'foo')  # inserting into an empty list
  >>> demo
  ['foo']
  >>> demo.insert(-1, 'bar')  # inserting before the last element
  >>> demo
  ['bar', 'foo']
  >>> demo.insert(-1, 'spam') # inserting before the last element
  ['bar', 'spam', 'foo']
  ```

  Just use *appending* to add elements to the end of a list:

  ```
  solution.append("1")
  ```

  and

  ```
  solution.append("0")
  ```
- You skip processing the last bit. You need to iterate all the way to `len(bin_input_1)`:

  ```
  for x in xrange(len(bin_input_1)):
  ```

With those 3 fixes applied, your code works and produces the expected output.

Your code is indeed re-inventing standard wheels in the Python language and standard library:

- Rather than manually XOR every bit, use the `^` operator to work on a whole byte at a time.
- Use the [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) and [`binascii.unhexlify()` functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to convert between hexadecimal and bytes.
- In Python 2, use the [`bytearray()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) to work with binary data as a sequence of integers, this is *much* easier to apply XOR operations to.
- Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two sequences together, pairing up elements from both.

Put together as a Python 2 solution:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def XORfunction(input_1, input_2):
    input_1 = bytearray(unhexlify(input_1))
    input_2 = bytearray(unhexlify(input_2))
    return hexlify(bytearray(
        a ^ b for a, b in zip(input_1, input_2)))
```

In Python 3, you can simply omit the first two `bytearray()` calls, and replace the last with `bytes()`.